# javascript loading only after refreshing page

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline

I'm using Rails 4. I have a javascript file, app/assets/javascripts/exotic_fonts.js, which adds some javascript functionality to fonts. When I load the homepage this javascript file is automatically loaded on the homepage, however it's not loaded automatically on other pages such as /user/show and the functionality is missing. However if I refresh the page, then the javascript file is loaded and the functionality is back. I was wondering how I can fix it.

Also, is it possible to load only some of the javascript files on a certain page?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using turbolinks?

Comment: Yes, I think Rails 4 uses turbolinks by default.

Comment: Turbolinks can cause problems with JavaScript. I would suggest you switch it off to see if the problem continues. If you decide to keep using it, take a look at this page: http://reed.github.io/turbolinks-compatibility/

Answer (score 1):

You can use following snippet to fix this issue. Now your js code will works with turbolinks.

```
ready = ->

// Your javascriptcode goes here

$(document).ready(ready)
$(document).on('page:load', ready)
```

Comment: Hi Murtza, Thanks for your answer. I tried it but it didn't work. Although I included all the javascript in the ready function, the only explanation is that maybe I'm missisng something. I tried the jquery.turbolinks gem and everything worked. Is there a downside to using jquery.turbolinks? Thanks.