# Rails 4: Angular and JS only loading after page refresh

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, ruby-on-rails-4

Rails 4 application using AngularJS v1.2.13.

I have a view that will, once loaded, populate itself with data loaded asynchronously from the server.

Currently I get the naked `{{content/scope variable}}` displayed when I navigate to this page.

However, a simple refresh of that page makes the view and the Angular app function perfectly.

It's not the `ng-bind` issue as it really seems like `JS` is broken on the initial load rather than just late in loading.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Disabling turbolinks seemed to have solve the issue for the moment. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19635355/javascript-loading-only-after-refreshing-page?rq=1#comment-29154424

I added Rails 4 to the title as that was the part that relates to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Installing this gem https://github.com/kossnocorp/jquery.turbolinks solved the problem.

The alternative was to disable turbolinks by adding data-no-turbolink to the body tags of layouts where I didn't want to use it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I think you need to bootstrap Angular manually to play nice with turbolinks...

In you code you should have something like:

```
angular.module("YourApplication")
```

You need to replace the previous code with the following code in order to bootstrap Angular manually.

```
angular.module('YourApplication').run(['$compile', '$rootScope', '$document', function($compile, $rootScope, $document) {
   return $document.on('page:load', function() {
      var body, compiled;
      body = angular.element('body');
      compiled = $compile(body.html())($rootScope);
      return body.html(compiled);
   });
}])
```

Answer (score 0):

Disable turbolinks seems not to be a good solution, since it became the default in Rails 4.
Turbolinks overrides the normal page loading process, the event angular automatic initialization relies on doesn't fire on page reload. Read [How turbolinks works](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#how-turbolinks-works) and [How Angular does in automatic initialization](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap) for more detail.

To overcome the conflict, just bootstrap angular manually

```
$(document).on 'page:load', ->
  $('[ng-app]').each ->
    module = $(this).attr('ng-app')
    angular.bootstrap(this, [module])
```